# Rename-Item throwing error when path contains '>'

Tags: powershell

When I try to rename a path that contains '<' or '>' i get the 
`Illegal characters in path` error. Strangely Rename-Item can handle other special characters like '#'. 
I refuse to belive that rename-item can't handle the '<' char. Does it needs to be escaped somehow?

I'm using the [Get-FolderItem](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Deeply-Nested-Files-a2148fd7) cmdlet instead of `Get-ChildItem` (due to pathlength restrictions on gci) and passing Rename-Item a object with a fullname prop like so

Edit: I'm a noob, it's `›` and not `>`

```
Rename-Item -LiteralPath $fileWithChar.FullName -NewName $newNameWithoutChar
```

Both $filleWithChar and $newNameWithoutChar are strings. 
I've tried using both -path and literalPath and it still throws the error.

Comment: What OS? `<` and `>` are not valid file system name characters on Windows (see [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx)).

Comment: Windows, and that's exactly why I want to get rid of them.  It's a shortcut that links to a website that has a name like "foo > bar" and i want to remove the ">"

Comment: `<` and `>` are input and output (respectively) redirection characters - they are not and never have been valid in Windows file names. How did you manage to get this character into a file name at all?

Comment: What is the exact filename right now?

Comment: I don't know, this is data that was given to me. It's a bunch of .url shortcuts that contain the character.
The filename is `website.com > regions > frontpage.url`

Comment: What file system is this file sitting in? And are you certain that the character really is `>` (ASCII character 62 decimal, 3E hex)?

Comment: Oh damn I'm a noob, thanks Bill. I didn't think to actually check that. PS thinks it's > but it's actually the › char. 8250 decimal 203A hex. So I need to catch all ascii chars?

Comment: The PowerShell console will convert the character when you paste it (not helpful in this case). Try using the ISE or saving your command in a script.

Comment: The trouble seems to stem from using the get-folderitem cmdlet rather then `Get-ChildItem`. 
`Rename-Item` has no problem renaming when passed an object from GCI, but `Get-FolderItem` casts the filename to a string, which seems to turn the `›` into `>`

Comment: Ahh and this seems to be because Robocopy interpets the `›` "right pointing single guillemet" (as it's apperently called) as a greater-then sign. 
So next question is: how do you make Robo support unicode chars? /Unicode and /Unilog is a complete mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`robocopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) is a Unicode application **on demand**, see following *Logging options* switches:

> ```
>       /unicode : Display the status output as Unicode text
>   /UNILOG:file : Output status to Unicode Log file (overwrite)
>  /UNILOG+:file : Output status to Unicode Log file (append)
> ```

Below is improved [`Get-FolderItem.ps1` script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Deeply-Nested-Files-a2148fd7). Pay your attention to changes:

- **line 135** `$params.AddRange(@("/L", … ,"/R:0","/W:0"))`
- *changed* `$params.AddRange(@("/L", … ,"/R:0","/W:0","/UNILOG:robolog.txt"))`
- **line 158** `Invoke-Expression $Script | ForEach {`
- *changed* `Invoke-Expression $Script | Out-Null; Get-Content robolog.txt | ForEach {`

**Sample output** proves Unicode awareness (some names are *pretty nonsensical*, sorry):

```
PS D:\PShell> . D:\Downloads\Get-FolderItem.ps1

PS D:\PShell> $x=Get-ChildItem -path "D:\bat\UnASCII Names\*"  | Get-FolderItem
WARNING: D:\bat\UnASCII Names\ěščřžýáíé.txt is not a directory and will be skipped

PS D:\PShell> $x.FullName
D:\bat\UnASCII Names\MathBoldScript ()\Mathematical Bold Script.txt
D:\bat\UnASCII Names\Türkçe (Türkiye)\çğüşöıĞÜİŞÇÖ\ĞÜİŞÇÖçğüşöı.txt
D:\bat\UnASCII Names\‹angles›\‹angles›.txt

PS D:\PShell>
```

**Improved script** uses an auxiliary file:

```
Function Get-FolderItem {
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
            Lists all files under a specified folder regardless of character limitation on path depth.

        .DESCRIPTION
            Lists all files under a specified folder regardless of character limitation on path depth.

        .PARAMETER Path
            The type name to list out available constructors and parameters

        .PARAMETER Filter
            Optional parameter to specify a specific file or file type. Wildcards (*) allowed.
            Default is '*.*'

        .PARAMETER ExcludeFile
            Exclude Files matching given names/paths/wildcards

        .PARAMETER MaxAge
            Exclude files older than n days.

        .PARAMETER MinAge
            Exclude files newer than n days.     

        .EXAMPLE
            Get-FolderItem -Path "C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\PowerShell Scripts"

            LastWriteTime : 4/25/2012 12:08:06 PM
            FullName      : C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\PowerShell Scripts\3_LevelDeep_ACL.ps1
            Name          : 3_LevelDeep_ACL.ps1
            ParentFolder  : C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\PowerShell Scripts
            Length        : 4958

            LastWriteTime : 5/29/2012 6:30:18 PM
            FullName      : C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\PowerShell Scripts\AccountAdded.ps1
            Name          : AccountAdded.ps1
            ParentFolder  : C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\PowerShell Scripts
            Length        : 760

            LastWriteTime : 4/24/2012 5:48:57 PM
            FullName      : C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\PowerShell Scripts\AccountCreate.ps1
            Name          : AccountCreate.ps1
            ParentFolder  : C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\PowerShell Scripts
            Length        : 52812

            Description
            -----------
            Returns all files under the PowerShell Scripts folder.

        .EXAMPLE
            $files = Get-ChildItem | Get-FolderItem
            $files | Group-Object ParentFolder | Select Count,Name

            Count Name
            ----- ----
               95 C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\2012 12 06 SysInt
               15 C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\DataMove
                5 C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\HTMLReportsinPowerShell
               31 C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\PoshPAIG_2_0_1
               30 C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\PoshPAIG_2_1_3
               67 C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\PoshWSUS_2_1
              437 C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\PowerShell Scripts
                9 C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\PowerShell Widgets
               92 C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\Working

            Description
            -----------
            This example shows Get-FolderItem taking pipeline input from Get-ChildItem and then saves
            the output to $files. Group-Object is used with $Files to show the count of files in each
            folder from where the command was executed.

        .EXAMPLE
            Get-FolderItem -Path $Pwd -MinAge 45

            LastWriteTime : 4/25/2012 12:08:06 PM
            FullName      : C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\PowerShell Scripts\3_LevelDeep_ACL.ps1
            Name          : 3_LevelDeep_ACL.ps1
            ParentFolder  : C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\PowerShell Scripts
            Length        : 4958

            LastWriteTime : 5/29/2012 6:30:18 PM
            FullName      : C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\PowerShell Scripts\AccountAdded.ps1
            Name          : AccountAdded.ps1
            ParentFolder  : C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\PowerShell Scripts
            Length        : 760

            Description
            -----------
            Gets files that have a LastWriteTime of greater than 45 days.

        .INPUTS
            System.String

        .OUTPUTS
            System.IO.RobocopyDirectoryInfo

        .NOTES
            Name: Get-FolderItem
            Author: Boe Prox
            Date Created: 31 March 2013
            Version History:
            Version 1.5 - 09 Jan 2014
                -Fixed bug in ExcludeFile parameter; would only work on one file exclusion and not multiple
                -Allowed for better streaming of output by Invoke-Expression to call the command vs. invoking
                a scriptblock and waiting for that to complete before display output.  
            Version 1.4 - 27 Dec 2013
                -Added FullPathLength property          
            Version 1.3 - 08 Nov 2013
                -Added ExcludeFile parameter
            Version 1.2 - 29 July 2013
                -Added Filter parameter for files
                -Fixed bug with ParentFolder property
                -Added default value for Path parameter            
            Version 1.1
                -Added ability to calculate file hashes
            Version 1.0
                -Initial Creation
    #>
    [cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Filter')]
    Param (
        [parameter(Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [Alias('FullName')]
        [string[]]$Path = $PWD,
        [parameter(ParameterSetName='Filter')]
        [string[]]$Filter = '*.*',    
        [parameter(ParameterSetName='Exclude')]
        [string[]]$ExcludeFile,              
        [parameter()]
        [int]$MaxAge,
        [parameter()]
        [int]$MinAge
    )
    Begin {
        $params = New-Object System.Collections.Arraylist
        $params.AddRange(@("/L","/S","/NJH","/BYTES","/FP","/NC","/NDL","/TS","/XJ","/R:0","/W:0","/UNILOG:robolog.txt"))
        If ($PSBoundParameters['MaxAge']) {
            $params.Add("/MaxAge:$MaxAge") | Out-Null
        }
        If ($PSBoundParameters['MinAge']) {
            $params.Add("/MinAge:$MinAge") | Out-Null
        }
    }
    Process {
        ForEach ($item in $Path) {
            Try {
                $item = (Resolve-Path -LiteralPath $item -ErrorAction Stop).ProviderPath
                If (-Not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $item -Type Container -ErrorAction Stop)) {
                    Write-Warning ("{0} is not a directory and will be skipped" -f $item)
                    Return
                }
                If ($PSBoundParameters['ExcludeFile']) {
                    $Script = "robocopy `"$item`" NULL $Filter $params /XF $($ExcludeFile  -join ',')"
                } Else {
                    $Script = "robocopy `"$item`" NULL $Filter $params"
                }
                Write-Verbose ("Scanning {0}" -f $item)

                Invoke-Expression $Script | Out-Null
                Get-Content robolog.txt | ForEach {
                    Try {
                        If ($_.Trim() -match "^(?<Size>\d+)\s(?<Date>\S+\s\S+)\s+(?<FullName>.*)") {
                           $object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                                ParentFolder = $matches.fullname -replace '(.*\\).*','$1'
                                FullName = $matches.FullName
                                Name = $matches.fullname -replace '.*\\(.*)','$1'
                                Length = [int64]$matches.Size
                                LastWriteTime = [datetime]$matches.Date
                                Extension = $matches.fullname -replace '.*\.(.*)','$1'
                                FullPathLength = [int] $matches.FullName.Length
                            }
                            $object.pstypenames.insert(0,'System.IO.RobocopyDirectoryInfo')
                            Write-Output $object
                        } Else {
                            Write-Verbose ("Not matched: {0}" -f $_)
                        }
                    } Catch {
                        Write-Warning ("{0}" -f $_.Exception.Message)
                        Return
                    }
                }
            } Catch {
                Write-Warning ("{0}" -f $_.Exception.Message)
                Return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh! I had been toying around with the unilog param, but i missed the part about piping the content of the new temp log to the foreach loop instead of the ouput from the script. Thanks @JosefZ